# $outputstring error with html class

Tags: php, html, css

So I'm not that great at php and I have a basic comment system that I'm trying to implement that calls and writes to a comments.php file.

everything works all well an good until I try and style the $outputstring a bit.

this is the code I have

```
$outputstring = "<br><p><span class="label">Name:</span> " .$name. "</p><br> <p><span class="label">Comment:</span>" .$message. "</p><br>";
```

I know whats causing it is the

```
<span class="label"></span>
```

but can anyone tell me why?

the script I got was just one off youtube while im experimenting with site building.

the full script is like this.

```
<?php
$act = $_POST['act'];
if($act == "post") {
$name = $_POST['name'];
$message  = $_POST ['message'];
@$fp = fopen("comments.php", 'a');
if (!$fp) {
    //The file could not be opened
    echo "There was an error! Please try again later!";
    exit;
} else {
    //The file was successfully opened, lets write the comment to it.
    $outputstring = "<br><p><span class="label">Name:</span> " .$name. "</p><br> <p><span class="label">Comment:</span>" .$message. "</p><br>";

    //Write to the file
    fwrite($fp, $outputstring, strlen($outputstring));

    //We are finished writing, close the file for security / memory management purposes
    fclose($fp);

    //Post the success message
    echo "Your post was successfully entered. Click <a href='index.php'>here</a> to continue.";
}
} else {
//We are not trying to post a comment, show the form.
?>
<h3>comments:</h3>
<hr/>
<?php include("comments.php"); ?>
<br><br>
<h3>Post a comment:</h3>
<form action="index.php" method="post">
<label>Name:<label>
<input type="text" name="name" value=""></input>
<br/>
<label>Comment:</label>
<textarea name="messages"></textarea>
<input type="hidden" name="act" value="post"></input>
<br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></input>
</form>
<?php
}
?>
```

If anyone could tell me what I would need to do to be able to add the span with a class that would be swell.

thanks.

Comment: You need to escape the quotes using `\"`, or use single quotes: `<span class=\"label\">` or `<span class='label'>`

Comment: Escape double quotes in `$outputstring` or use single quote

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use double quotes inside double quotes until you escape them with backslashes, in this case use single quotes instead like this

```
$outputstring = "<br><p><span class='label'>Name:</span> " .$name. "</p><br> <p><span class='label'>Comment:</span>" .$message. "</p><br>";
```

Comment: thanks so much, I learnt this like 2 days ago but forgot. I guess that's what I get for trying to power learn a bunch of new stuff 8 hours a day :\. ill mark you best.

Answer (score 0):

```
$outputstring = "<br><p><span class="label">Name:</span> " .$name. "</p><br> <p><span class="label">Comment:</span>" .$message. "</p><br>";
```

This line is wrong because you break your line delimiters. 
Use simple quotes instead of double quotes for the *class* attribute :

```
$outputstring = "<br><p><span class='label'>Name:</span> " .$name. "</p><br> <p><span class='label'>Comment:</span>" .$message. "</p><br>";
```

Or, as stated by chandresh_cool, escape your double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

`$outputstring = '<br><p><span class="label">Name:</span> ' .$name. '</p><br> <p><span class="label">Comment:</span>' .$message. '</p><br>';` This should solve your problem use '' when you don't have dynamic values.